# What happens when more than one AJAX event used for a component

Tags: exception, richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I am using `JSF 1.2`, `Richfaces 3.3.3` with Tomcat 6.
I have called two `AJAX` event methods for a single component and both event `reRender` the component.

My Sample code :

```
<h:outputLabel id="ct3lbl1" value="CT3 No " />                          
<rich:spacer width="1" height="1" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="ct3serial" value="#{PurchaseOrder.ct3SerialNo}" style="width:160px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{PurchaseOrder.ct3serialList}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange"   action="#{PurchaseOrder.loadSupDetails}"  ajaxSingle="true" reRender="ct3serial,tablepanel" />
    <a4j:support event="onblur" action="#{PurchaseOrder.ct3validate}"  ajaxSingle="true"    reRender="valctserial,ct3serial" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText id="valctserial"  value="#{PurchaseOrder.valct3serial}" style="color: red;" />
```

I stuck at an issue `Duplicate Id Exception` in auto generated client id.

My Question is using more than one `AJAX` request for a component and rendering the component is a reason for this exception.Suggest me to overcome this issue.

Comment: The value of the duplicate ID that was printed tells you exactly what's wrong. There's nothing wrong with using two events.

Comment: Which event will performed first  when we call both onchange and onblur event and value is changed (for onchange event).